# Access element over the router-outlet Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

```html
<side-nav [navTitle]="navTitle"></side-nav>
<router-outlet>

</router-outlet>
```

I  have navigation bar at the root component. I created `[navTitle]` with `@Input` Decorator inside the `side-nav` component. `side-nav` component is placed in another component(`root-component`). However I want access `[navTitle]` and change from component which loaded inside the router-outlet acording to which component is loaded. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Share data through service

Comment: @CommercialSuicide can you explain how to create such a service and where to Inject it?

Comment: I've added the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass any data to `router-outlet` as to regular component (at the current version of Angular it's not possible, may be it will be added in the future), so the following syntax is **invalid**:

```
<router-outlet [dataToPass]="'something'"></router-outlet>
```

In provided case, you can use services to share data between your components, and I think, that using observable is the best way, because you will get the updated version of data realtime:

**data.service.ts**

```
// Other service stuff
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  private navTitle$: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>('Default nav title');

  public setNavTitle(newNavTitle: string): void {
    // Sets new value, every entity, which is subscribed to changes (`getNavTitle().subscribe(...)`) will get new value every time it changes
    this.navTitle$.next(newNavTitle);
  }

  public getNavTitle(): Observable<string> {
    // Allow to `subscribe` on changes and get the value every time it changes
    return this.navTitle$.asObservable();
  }
}
```

**side-nav.component.ts**

```
// Other component stuff
export class SideNavComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public navTitle: string = '';
  private getNavTitleSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private _dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Will update the value of `this.navTitle` every time, when you will call `setNavTitle('data')` in data service
    this.getNavTitleSubscription = this._dataService.getNavTitle()
      .subscribe((navTitle: string) => this.navTitle = navTitle);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // You have to `unsubscribe()` from subscription on destroy to avoid some kind of errors
    this.getNavTitleSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

And any component, which is loaded in that `router-outlet`:

**any.component.ts**

```
// Other component stuff
export class SideNavComponent implements OnInit {
  private navTitleToSet: string = 'Any title';

  constructor(private _dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Set title from current component
    this._dataService.setNavTitle(this.navTitleToSet);
  }
}
```

In such case you don't really need to pass the value from `root` component to `side-nav`, because you already have a `subscription` in `side-nav` component and you will have access to the latest value. If you need `navTitle` in both `root` and `side-nav` components, you can just move the logic with `subscription` to `root`.

And here is the working [**STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bezcnw?file=src/app/side-nav.component.ts).

Comment: @ultimatex, I've updated the answer, you can find the working stackblitz at the bottom

Comment: Sorry I have mistakenly typed `this.navTitle =newNavTitle` instead `this.navTitle$.next(newNavTitle);`. It is working like charm.

Comment: @ultimatex, nice to hear that

Answer (score 1):

You can use a service to communicate between components. I have created a short example which would give you a glimpse of how it can be done.

The service being a singleton, has only one instance and hence the properties remain the same.

Hope it helps.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-paziug?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts